# composer command not work - PHP Warning: Phar::mapPhar

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

I cannot run the composer command. I'm using windows cmd.

Inside C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin, I can do `php composer.phar` and it works.

But if do `composer` or `composer.bat`, I get this :

```
 PHP Warning:  Phar::mapPhar(/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/c:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/c:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar on line 23
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'unable to open phar for reading "/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/c:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar"' in /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/c:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:23
Stack trace:
#0 /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/c:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar(23): Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/c:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar on line 23
```

What's wrong ?

I'm using the cygwin php in my path (cygwin/bin).

It works if I use a new php installation. But I want to keep "cygwin/bin" in my path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it !

Removing "c:\cygwin64\bin" in the path.
Adding new php installation in path : "c:\php"

Adding new system variable : "CYGWIN_HOME", with value c:\cygwin64.

This way, using windows cmd, composer will use the php in the path ("c:\php").

And using cygwin, composer will use the php in "cygwin\bin" (because of the CYGWIN_HOME variable).